# ggplot and dplyr showing standard error

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a plot where I plot multiple lines and for each point I'd like to show the error bars.  I need to use

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin), width=0.25) + xlab('points')
```

My question is how best to make the ymax an ymin columns

Currently the data frame looks like this

```
data1 <- data.frame(
  group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), 
  x= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
  z= c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80))     # sample data matrix

data2 = as.data.frame (data1 %>% group_by( group  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    MU_Y= mean(y),
    upper_limit_Y =MU_Y+(1.96*sd(y, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(y)))),
    lower_limit_Y = MU_Y-(1.96*sd(y, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(y)))),
    MU_Z= mean(z),
    upper_limit_Z =MU_Z+(1.96*sd(z, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(z)))),
    lower_limit_Z = MU_Z-(1.96*sd(z, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(z))))
  )  %>% 
  gather(key =Metric, value = Value  , 
         #c(MU_Y,lower_limit_Y,upper_limit_Y,MU_Z, upper_limit_Z,lower_limit_Z) )
          c(MU_Y,MU_Z) )
)


  group upper_limit_Y lower_limit_Y upper_limit_Z lower_limit_Z Metric Value
1     A      3.765175      1.234825      37.65175      12.34825   MU_Y   2.5
2     B      7.765175      5.234825      77.65175      52.34825   MU_Y   6.5
3     A      3.765175      1.234825      37.65175      12.34825   MU_Z  25.0
4     B      7.765175      5.234825      77.65175      52.34825   MU_Z  65.0

ggplot(data2, aes(x = group, y= Value, group = Metric ))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

I need to make 2 new columns to the data frame ymin and ymax that are the appropriate upper/lower limits. the new column that are added should look like this (I didnt copy all decimal places):

```
 ymin    ymax
    1.23..   3.76..
    5.23..   7.76..
    12.34..  37.65..
     52...    77.65...
```

then I'd be able to plot the lines and the error bars for each point.

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x = group, y= Value, group = Metric ))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin), width=0.25) + 
  xlab('points')
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping your dply chain with as.data.frame? If you really need to use as.data.frame, add it to the end of the chain `%>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: thanks! any thoughts on the question?

Comment: Suspecting the gather is causing more problems than it fixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have your `gather` in the wrong place.

```
data2 <- data1 %>% 
  gather(key = Metric, value = Value, -group, -x) %>%
  group_by(group, Metric) %>%
  summarise(
    MU = mean(Value),
    SD = sd(Value, na.rm = TRUE),
    N = sum(!is.na(Value)),
    upper_limit = MU + SD/sqrt(N),
    lower_limit = MU - SD/sqrt(N)
  )


ggplot(data2, aes(x = group, y= MU, group = Metric ))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=upper_limit, ymin=lower_limit), width=0.25) + 
  xlab('points')
```

Does this do what you want?